# Running a program in parallel while using another python script

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing

I am trying to get a toy problem to work in parallel so that I can apply it to something more complex. I am importing a different file that has a class defined in it, and simply wish to run the program on 4 engines.

Here is my utility file named testing_script

```
import scipy

class classy(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def a(self, y):
        return scipy.arange(y*self.x)

def callclassy(x,y):
    c = classy(x)
    return c.a(y)
```

The file that I'd like to run in parallel:

```
import testing_script
import IPython.parallel

pc = IPython.parallel.Client()

lv = pc.load_balanced_view()

@IPython.parallel.require('testing_script')
def Func(x):
    return testing_script.callclassy(x[0],x[1])

r = lv.map(Func, [[1,2],[3,2],[4,3],[5,2]])
```

---

This runs without error, but r returns AsyncMapResult: Func and r.get(5) times out. I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: This works fine for me if I add a `print(r.get())` cal to the end, as long I start a hub via `ipcluster -n 4` beforehand.

Comment: Well that's weird cause it wont run on my computer, it just says TimeoutError: Result not ready. I typed "ipcluster start -n 4" into the command prompt before hand and it said the engines were up and running.

I'm using enthought's Canopy on windows 8.

Comment: Figured it out for anyone in the future as dumb as I: you have to run the cluster in the same filepath as where your programs are